# How to combine logging and unit-testing in java?

Tags: java, logging, exception, junit

I've just started my very first toy-project in java and faced with misunderstanding of how it should be done. I'm using java.util.logging and  JUnit4 library.

For example we have something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());
  public static void SomeMethod() {
     try{
       ...some code...
     } catch(Exception e){
         log.warning("Something bad happened");
     }
  }
```

And the unit-test will be:

```
@Test
public void SomeClassTest(){
  SomeClass.SomeMethod();
}
```

But there will never be an exception, cause I've already handled it in method.

Should I generate new exception in catch-block? Or may be using junit combined with logging is not a good idea?

Comment: Your problem is not about logging but exception handling and when to catch or not it seems...

Comment: I am getting the impression that you want to test only those methods that throw any kind of exception which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method that does not throw an exception (and returns the expected value if any) **is meant to work correctly** from the perspective of a **user**.

So you should use `try - catch` **and** *logging* inside a method, when you can catch an exception and the method will still work correctly (do something else when this error happens for example but still return the expected result or perform the supposed operation).

*In this case the unit test should check if the operation was performed correctly (if the object is in the expected state and the result value (in your case void) is correct*

You should **rethrow** the exception (and usually not log it, but that depends) if the method cannot do what it is supposed to do when the exception occurs.

*In this case the unit test should check if the operation was performed correctly (if the object is in the expected state and the result value (in your case void) is correct if there is no exception, and if there is an exception it should check if this exception was expected*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test that the exception is thrown then you would have to re-throw, or not catch, the `Exception`.

Otherwise you can unit test that the `class` is in the correct state after the exception, i.e. that the exception was correctly handled.

I would say one other thing. **Don't** `catch(Exception e)`, catch the specific exception you are expecting. Otherwise you will handle other, unexpected, exceptions in the same way and that is really quite dangerous.

Comment: catching specific exceptions is a useful hint to create better code!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rethrow the caught exception:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());

    public static void SomeMethod() {
        try {
            // your stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warning("Something happened");
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but was hoping of finding some other way, because this seems to me not elegant enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I generate new exception in catch-block?

No. don't do that! you can test your existing code! when you only want to log the message but you don't want to handle it in the method that call `someMethod()` don't throw it!

> using junit combined with logging is not a good idea?

both are good ideas and can be used together without problems.

Think about how you can test your method. i would not modify the code just that you can easily test it. because you WANTED to catch the exception and log for a reason.

try verifing what variables or objects are modified in your test-method